# Reload page or dynamically update content after switching language?

Tags: angular, web, single-page-application, angular-translate, vue-i18n

I'm struggling with design of [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) handling, what should we do after a user has changed the language?

1. Reload the browser with the selected language
2. Dynamically update the labels and other translatable things without a refresh

Any suggestion on this?

BTW, keep in mind we build a SPA project, the project size won't be as large as an E-commerce portal

Comment: If you can, the better user experience is [2] 'Dynamically update the labels and other translatable things without a refresh'

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions with i18n (**you will need reload page when language is changed, angualr i18n can't update displayed data in runtime**):

1. Use some subdomain like en.domain.com & fr.domain.com and when language changed navigate user
2. Using localStorage (or other storage) for storing selected language
3. Use some prefix (like in first) domain.com/en OR domain.com/fr

With using ngx-translate u can saw actually language when it changed (runtime updated).

Thanks!